# Google Maps and Images - RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: maps, range, call

I got problem with Google Maps and tryng to fix it, but still cant figure it out.
On my website gopal.aboutmark.net i got under tab Mapa a Google map and under tab Virtual tour(translated from Czech) i got image viewer from google maps..

It still shows me error in console
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

And I cant figure it out.
Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

i think I found the cause of this bug… 
if you've been using marker mode and we're using the Lat/Long/zoom/title fields but allowing an unlimited number of markers. So if you created an entry with more than one marker it would work on the first save but fire the rangeError on edit. I’m assuming this is because the plugin was only expecting one marker but was getting an array of markers?
The fix…
Simply leaving the Lat/Long/zoom/title dropdowns blank should fix the bug